# Exception thrown when using setObject() on PreparedStatement in ODI

Tags: java, oracle-data-integrator

`java.lang.IllegalAccessException` is thrown when I use `setObject()` on `PreparedStatement` in ODI

**What am I developing** : Writing a knowledge module in ODI(11.1.1) to load data from another source to Oracle table.
Code works fine when run in eclipse.But gives the following error when run in ODI.

-> Getting inputs from other sites, I tried replacing ucp.jar with newer version 11.2.0.2
The README.txt states that this version resolves a known bug of IllegalAccessException,
but I still face the same error when executed in ODI.

```
Error in method invocation: Cannot access method setObject( int, java.lang.Object ) in 'class oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper' :java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class bsh.Reflect can not access a member of class oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper with modifiers "public" : at Line: 433 : in file: inline evaluation of: `` //********Start of OdiSfdcLogger class************** import java.io.File; impor . . . '' : pStatement .setObject ( i + 1 ,( ( Map ) iNotifications .get ( 0 ) ) .get ( sfdcColums .get ( i ) ) ) 
at bsh.BSHMethodInvocation.eval(Unknown Source)
at bsh.BSHPrimaryExpression.eval(Unknown Source)
at bsh.BSHPrimaryExpression.eval(Unknown Source)
at bsh.BSHBlock.evalBlock(Unknown Source)
at bsh.BSHBlock.eval(Unknown Source)
at bsh.BSHBlock.eval(Unknown Source)
at bsh.BSHForStatement.eval(Unknown Source)
at bsh.BSHSwitchStatement.eval(Unknown Source)
at bsh.BSHBlock.evalBlock(Unknown Source)
at bsh.BSHBlock.eval(Unknown Source)
at bsh.BshMethod.invokeImpl(Unknown Source)
at bsh.BshMethod.invoke(Unknown Source)
at bsh.BshMethod.invoke(Unknown Source)
at bsh.This.invokeMethod(Unknown Source)
at com.streaming.ck.ConnectOracle.renderData(BeanShell Generated via ASM (www.objectweb.org))
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at bsh.Reflect.invokeOnMethod(Unknown Source)
at bsh.Reflect.invokeObjectMethod(Unknown Source)
at bsh.Name.invokeMethod(Unknown Source)
at bsh.BSHMethodInvocation.eval(Unknown Source)
at bsh.BSHPrimaryExpression.eval(Unknown Source)
at bsh.BSHPrimaryExpression.eval(Unknown Source)
at bsh.BSHBlock.evalBlock(Unknown Source)
at bsh.BSHBlock.eval(Unknown Source)
at bsh.BSHBlock.eval(Unknown Source)
at bsh.BSHWhileStatement.eval(Unknown Source)
at bsh.BSHBlock.evalBlock(Unknown Source)
at bsh.BSHBlock.eval(Unknown Source)
at bsh.BSHBlock.eval(Unknown Source)
at bsh.BSHTryStatement.eval(Unknown Source)
at bsh.Interpreter.eval(Unknown Source)
at bsh.Interpreter.eval(Unknown Source)
at bsh.Interpreter.eval(Unknown Source)
at bsh.util.BeanShellBSFEngine.eval(Unknown Source)
at bsh.util.BeanShellBSFEngine.exec(Unknown Source)
at com.sunopsis.dwg.codeinterpretor.SnpScriptingInterpretor.execInBSFEngine(SnpScriptingInterpretor.java:322)
at com.sunopsis.dwg.codeinterpretor.SnpScriptingInterpretor.exec(SnpScriptingInterpretor.java:170)
at com.sunopsis.dwg.dbobj.SnpSessTaskSql.scripting(SnpSessTaskSql.java:2472)
at oracle.odi.runtime.agent.execution.cmd.ScriptingExecutor.execute(ScriptingExecutor.java:47)
at oracle.odi.runtime.agent.execution.cmd.ScriptingExecutor.execute(ScriptingExecutor.java:1)
at oracle.odi.runtime.agent.execution.TaskExecutionHandler.handleTask(TaskExecutionHandler.java:50)
at com.sunopsis.dwg.dbobj.SnpSessTaskSql.processTask(SnpSessTaskSql.java:2913)
at com.sunopsis.dwg.dbobj.SnpSessTaskSql.treatTask(SnpSessTaskSql.java:2625)
at com.sunopsis.dwg.dbobj.SnpSessStep.treatAttachedTasks(SnpSessStep.java:577)
at com.sunopsis.dwg.dbobj.SnpSessStep.treatSessStep(SnpSessStep.java:468)
at com.sunopsis.dwg.dbobj.SnpSession.treatSession(SnpSession.java:2128)
at oracle.odi.runtime.agent.processor.impl.StartSessRequestProcessor$2.doAction(StartSessRequestProcessor.java:366)
at oracle.odi.core.persistence.dwgobject.DwgObjectTemplate.execute(DwgObjectTemplate.java:216)
at oracle.odi.runtime.agent.processor.impl.StartSessRequestProcessor.doProcessStartSessTask(StartSessRequestProcessor.java:300)
at oracle.odi.runtime.agent.processor.impl.StartSessRequestProcessor.access$0(StartSessRequestProcessor.java:292)
at oracle.odi.runtime.agent.processor.impl.StartSessRequestProcessor$StartSessTask.doExecute(StartSessRequestProcessor.java:855)
at oracle.odi.runtime.agent.processor.task.AgentTask.execute(AgentTask.java:126)
at oracle.odi.runtime.agent.support.DefaultAgentTaskExecutor$2.run(DefaultAgentTaskExecutor.java:82)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Any suggestions?

The code for PreparedStatement :

```
public void renderData(ArrayList notifications, ArrayList sfdcColumnsList, String         oracleColumnsString, String tableName) 
        throws Exception {

    PreparedStatement pStatement = null;
    String eventType = (String)((Map) notifications.get(0)).get("eventType");
    String sql= null;

    switch (typeOfEvent(eventType)) {
    case CREATE:System.out.println("In Created case ---------->");

        sql = "INSERT INTO "+ tableName + "(" +oracleColumnsString+")" + " VALUES (";

            for(int i =0;i<sfdcColumnsList.size()-1;i++){
                sql = sql+"?,";
            }
            sql = sql + "?)";
            System.out.println("SQL QUERY ::::::: "+sql);

            pStatement =  conn.prepareStatement(sql);

            for(int i=0;i<sfdcColumnsList.size();i++){
                String sdfcData =(String) ((Map) notifications.get(0)).get(sfdcColumnsList.get(i));
                System.out.println("Check data :::::: " +sdfcData);
            pStatement.setObject(i+1,((Map)notifications.get(0)).get(sfdcColumnsList.get(i));
                    }

        break;

        //Rest of the cases : 
        }

        try {
        pStatement.setEscapeProcessing(true);
        boolean checkDataconn = pStatement.execute();
        System.out.println("Inserted/updated/deleted record : "+checkDataconn);

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Could you plz add the Prepare Statement code.

Comment: @SureshkumarPanneerselvan 
Added the code.

Comment: Check the sql value after for loop and check the list value. Do debug by applying the value. The issue may be with the type i think. Lets try..

Comment: @SureshkumarPanneerselvan : The SQL is correct, have already checked. Like I said earlier, this code works fine when run in eclipse, but when run via ODI(Oracle Data Integrator), it gives IllelegalAccessException, It throws this exception from **setObject()** method